# Can fable reconcile hierarchical time series, where the hierarchy has different depth at different nodes?

Tags: r, time-series, hierarchical-data, fable-r

I am using the fable package to obtain forecasts on a set of hierarchical time series. I would like to specify a hierarchy, that does not have the same depth at all nodes.

**Realistic example:**

- Time series B1 and B2 are summed to time series M1.
- Time series M1 and M2 are summed to time series T, which is at the top of the hierachy.
- Time series M2 is not the sum of a set of time series; it is it's own time series.

Creating a small random data set in `tsibble` format:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tsibble)
library(fable)

set.seed(1)
B1 <- rnorm(12, mean = 5) + (1:12)
B2 <- rnorm(12, mean = 5)
M2 <- rnorm(12, mean = 25)

ts_data <- tibble(value = c(B1, B2, M2), 
                  month = rep(yearmonth(paste("2020", 1:12, sep="-")), 3), 
                  B = c(rep("B1", 12), rep("B2", 12), rep("B3", 12)), 
                  M = c(rep("M1", 24), rep("M2", 12))) %>%
  as_tsibble(key = c("B", "M"), index = month)
```

Estimating separate ARIMA models on each of the 3 time series, aggregating and forecasting:

```
fcsts <- ts_data %>%
  # Specify hierarchy
  aggregate_key(M / B, value = sum(value)) %>%
  # Fit models
  model(arima = ARIMA(value)) %>%
  # Set up reconciliation
  mutate(mint = min_trace(arima)) %>%
  # Produce the forecasts
  forecast(h = 1)
```

The reason, why I am worried that the result might be wrong, is that I can create a pathological example, where the reconciliation gives smaller confidence intervals, even though there is no actual aggregation:

**Pathological example:**

- Time series B3 is the child of M2, which is the child of T.

I create a dataset for this example by subsetting the previous one:

```
ts_data_2 <- ts_data %>% 
  filter(B == "B3")
```

Again estimating separate ARIMA models, aggregating and forecasting:

```
fcsts_2 <- ts_data_2 %>%
  # Specify hierarchy
  aggregate_key(M / B, value = sum(value)) %>%
  # Fit models
  model(arima = ARIMA(value)) %>%
  # Set up reconciliation
  mutate(mint = min_trace(arima)) %>%
  # Produce the forecasts
  forecast(h = 6)
```

The result is as follows:

```
> fcsts_2
# A fable: 6 x 6 [1M]
# Key:     M, B, .model [6]
  M            B            .model    month value .distribution
  <chr>        <chr>        <chr>     <mth> <dbl> <dist>       
1 M2           B3           arima  2021 Jan  24.9 N(25, 0.63)  
2 M2           <aggregated> arima  2021 Jan  24.9 N(25, 0.63)  
3 <aggregated> <aggregated> arima  2021 Jan  24.9 N(25, 0.63)  
4 M2           B3           mint   2021 Jan  24.9 N(25, 0.21)  
5 M2           <aggregated> mint   2021 Jan  24.9 N(25, 0.21)  
6 <aggregated> <aggregated> mint   2021 Jan  24.9 N(25, 0.21)
```

The variance decreases from 0.63 in the original ARIMA model to 0.21, even though there is no actual aggregation. Of course, this is an example, where reconciliation shouldn't be used at all, but the fact that the variance decreases here makes me worry that the reconciliation doesn't work correctly in the realistic example.

Is there a way to specify the model in the realistic example to avoid aggregation from B3 up to M2? (I have tried using NA instead of the level "B3" in column B, but this doesn't work.)

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is that the reconciliation is based on an estimate of the covariance matrix of the errors, and the default setting uses a diagonal matrix which results in a severe underestimate when there is a degenerate hierarchy.

A better result (although still with some bias) occurs when you use the `mint_shrink` option:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tsibble)
library(fable)

set.seed(1)
B1 <- rnorm(12, mean = 5) + (1:12) 
B2 <- rnorm(12, mean = 5) 
M2 <- rnorm(12, mean = 25) 

ts_data <- tibble(value = c(B1, B2, M2),  
                  month = rep(yearmonth(paste("2020", 1:12, sep="-")), 3),  
                  B = c(rep("B1", 12), rep("B2", 12), rep("B3", 12)),  
                  M = c(rep("M1", 24), rep("M2", 12))) %>% 
  as_tsibble(key = c("B", "M"), index = month) 
ts_data_2 <- ts_data %>%  
  filter(B == "B3") 
ts_data_2 %>% 
  # Specify hierarchy 
  aggregate_key(M / B, value = sum(value)) %>% 
  # Fit models 
  model(arima = ARIMA(value)) %>% 
  # Set up reconciliation 
  mutate(mint = min_trace(arima, method="mint_shrink")) %>% 
  # Produce the forecasts 
  forecast(h = 6)
#> # A fable: 36 x 6 [1M]
#> # Key:     M, B, .model [6]
#>    M     B     .model    month       value .mean
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>     <mth>      <dist> <dbl>
#>  1 M2    B3    arima  2021 Jan N(25, 0.63)  24.9
#>  2 M2    B3    arima  2021 Feb N(25, 0.63)  24.9
#>  3 M2    B3    arima  2021 Mar N(25, 0.63)  24.9
#>  4 M2    B3    arima  2021 Apr N(25, 0.63)  24.9
#>  5 M2    B3    arima  2021 May N(25, 0.63)  24.9
#>  6 M2    B3    arima  2021 Jun N(25, 0.63)  24.9
#>  7 M2    B3    mint   2021 Jan N(25, 0.56)  24.9
#>  8 M2    B3    mint   2021 Feb N(25, 0.56)  24.9
#>  9 M2    B3    mint   2021 Mar N(25, 0.56)  24.9
#> 10 M2    B3    mint   2021 Apr N(25, 0.56)  24.9
#> # … with 26 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically, fable allows you to remove aggregations / disaggregations that you don't want. To remove the B3 level, you can use:

```r
library(fpp3)
B1 <- rnorm(12, mean = 5) + (1:12)
B2 <- rnorm(12, mean = 5)
M2 <- rnorm(12, mean = 25)

ts_data <- tibble(value = c(B1, B2, M2), 
                  month = rep(yearmonth(paste("2020", 1:12, sep="-")), 3), 
                  B = c(rep("B1", 12), rep("B2", 12), rep("B3", 12)), 
                  M = c(rep("M1", 24), rep("M2", 12))) %>%
  as_tsibble(key = c("B", "M"), index = month)

ts_data %>%
  # Specify hierarchy
  aggregate_key(M / B, value = sum(value)) %>% 
  # Remove redundant nodes from hierarchy (#226)
  filter(!(B == "B3")) %>% 
  # Fit models
  model(arima = ARIMA(value)) %>%
  # Set up reconciliation
  mutate(mint = min_trace(arima)) %>%
  # Produce the forecasts
  forecast(h = 1)
#> # A fable: 10 x 6 [1M]
#> # Key:     M, B, .model [10]
#>    M            B            .model    month        value .mean
#>    <chr>        <chr>        <chr>     <mth>       <dist> <dbl>
#>  1 M1           B1           arima  2021 Jan   N(19, 1.9) 18.5 
#>  2 M1           B1           mint   2021 Jan   N(18, 1.2) 17.6 
#>  3 M1           B2           arima  2021 Jan    N(4.9, 1)  4.86
#>  4 M1           B2           mint   2021 Jan N(4.3, 0.81)  4.26
#>  5 M1           <aggregated> arima  2021 Jan   N(20, 3.6) 20.4 
#>  6 M1           <aggregated> mint   2021 Jan   N(22, 1.2) 21.9 
#>  7 M2           <aggregated> arima  2021 Jan  N(25, 0.62) 24.8 
#>  8 M2           <aggregated> mint   2021 Jan  N(25, 0.56) 24.7 
#>  9 <aggregated> <aggregated> arima  2021 Jan     N(46, 4) 45.8 
#> 10 <aggregated> <aggregated> mint   2021 Jan   N(47, 1.4) 46.6
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Your attempt to use `NA` in place of B3 is actually close to what I'm adding in the next version to better support unbalanced hierarchies. I will be exporting `agg_vec()` to allow you to create custom `<aggregated>` values, which can then be passed into `aggregate_key()`. I also hope to add a feature to `aggregate_key()` for detecting redundant nodes, and possibly removing them (https://github.com/tidyverts/fabletools/issues/226).

Comment: Note that the weird `!(B == "B3")` is required for v0.2.1 of fabletools, but has been fixed in the dev version to allow for `B != "B3"`. (https://github.com/tidyverts/fabletools/commit/db3fece827f26e2f90956f836ac0c0817624114d)

Comment: Thank you, Mitchell. I've updated to the newest version of the package(s) and tried your solution and it works like a charm. Too bad that I have to deal with an R server, where I can only run a slightly outdated version that doesn't seem to like the `!(B == "B3")`.

Comment: Using `!(B == "B3")` should work with the latest CRAN version of fabletools. `B != "B3"` should work with the latest development version of fabletools.